# How to handle unassigned IDs with anorm?

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

Anorm has the special type `anorm.Pk` for typed primary keys (and its subclass `anorm.NotAssigned`). This allows to assign a `NotAssigned` value if the database is responsible for generating the relevant key.

Is there an equivalent concept for foreign keys? I'm using type `Long` at the moment. However, if the foreign key is not yet known, I will have to assign a `null` value or replace the type by an `Option[Long]`. This feels like it's not the way it's meant to be done, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anorm doesn't offer functionality around relations.

Take your FK out of your model, but accept FKs as arguments to your CRUD, e.g. for creating a "Contrived" that belongs to a user:

```
def create(c: Contrived, userId: Long)
  DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  val id = SQL("""
      insert into c
      (first, second, login_id)
      values
      ({first}, {second}, {login_id})
      """).on(
    'first -> c.first,
    'second -> c.second,
    'login_id -> userId
```

...etc

Comment: This sounds like a good solution if you have seperate actions for the creation of `user`s and `c`s. But I'm using a single action in combination with repeated form values.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to say "I've answered your question" without trying to sound like a Richard :) Ask a separate question for that, because it veers off the question about if there's an FK equivalent to PK.